# Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável

Tags: suporte, moderação

O que um moderador pode fazer que um usuário com uma alta reputação não pode?

Pesquisei no Meta e no site, porém não encontrei.

Comment: Esse link explica legal: [Teoria da Moderação](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: @Math faz ai uma resposta em português ;)

Comment: Hehhe, eu ia dizer isso agora, se alguém puder traduzir e postar... :)

Comment: Na verdade o @Gabe já fez isso [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1095/3117), só que a publicação está excluída, é só pedir para ele copiar e colar aqui. Não quero levar o mérito dele :)

Comment: A central de ajuda explica: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: @bfavaretto basicamente o moderador cuida da fila de sinalizações e pra uma pergunta ser fechada/reaberta/movida precisa de pelo menos 1 voto de moderador?

Comment: @KaduAmaral O texto lá é meio confuso, mas quando diz que o voto do moderador "representa obrigatoriedade", significa que basta um voto do moderador para a ação (fechamento, exclusão, etc) ser executada. Então é como se nem fosse um "voto" mesmo (internamente, no sistema, isso é um voto).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Os moderadores ♦ têm os seguintes (super) poderes e privilégios a mais que os usuários confiáveis:

- Fechar e reabrir perguntas com um voto (ou seja, sozinhos).
- Migrar perguntas para outros sites da rede.
- Mesclar respostas de perguntas duplicadas.
- Excluir e desfazer exclusão de perguntas e respostas com um voto.
- Bloquear perguntas e respostas para que não possam ser editadas nem votadas.
- Excluir comentários com um voto, e desfazer a exclusão dos comentários que excluiu (não podemos ressuscitar comentários excluídos pelo próprio autor).
- Ver comentários excluídos.
- Ver perguntas e respostas excluídas no perfil dos autores, e fazer buscas por perguntas e respostas excluídas.
- Ver as sinalizações em perguntas e respostas, e quem sinalizou.
- Ver as sinalizações em comentários (mas não quem sinalizou).
- Enviar mensagens particulares, com cópia via email, para os usuários, em casos graves. A mensagem pode vir acompanhada de suspensão por tempo determinado.
- Suspender temporariamente usuários de uma ou mais filas de análise.
- Destruir conta de usuário utilizada para spam ou *trolling*.
- Criar sinônimos de tags, aprovar sinônimos sugeridos e mesclar tags (migrar perguntas de uma tag para outra).

Além disso, temos acesso a alguns relatórios e estatísticas adicionais para auxiliar as tomadas de decisão.

Comment: moderadores♦ não tem poderes, eles tem super poderes :)

Comment: E sobre destruir contas de usuários encrenqueiros, como spammers e sockpuppets? E o merge de contas de usuário? Como é essa parte?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Complementei, pois de fato podemos destruir contas de spammers/trolls. Mas não podemos fazer merge, isso precisamos solicitar a um CM.

Comment: Bacana, mas tem alguns privilégios ai que não são exclusivos de moderadores néh? O privilégio de criar sinônimos de tags eu ganhei agora com 3k de reputação.

Comment: @KaduAmaral Você pode *sugerir* um sinônimo, e com certas restrições (as duas tags precisam existir, e você precisa ter ganho pelo menos 5 votos em postagens numa delas, ou ambas, não lembro bem). A sugestão precisa ser votada por outros usuários com o mesmo privilégio, ou aprovada por um moderador. Já os moderadores podem criar qualquer sinônimo a qualquer momento, sem depender de ninguém.

Comment: Ahh, entendi.. Esse migrar perguntas de uma tag pra outra seria uma migração em massa, tipo migrar todas as perguntas da tag `function` para a tag `funções`, ou algo similar a alterar a tag na edição da pergunta?

Comment: @KaduAmaral É migração em massa.

Comment: @bfavaretto Podem também aprovar sugestões de sinônimos de tags com um voto?

Comment: @falsarella sim

Comment: @falsarella Fui agora na página de sinônimos pra ver se tinha coisa nova pra aprovar, mas nada :( A comunidade poderia sugerir mais sinônimos...

Comment: @bfavaretto Deve ter muito sinônimo por aqui no SOpt! Vi que precisa de 2500 para sugerir. =/ Talvez pudesse baixar essa barreira (assim como foi feito para adicionar tags). [Perguntei mais porque sugeri um sinônimo no SOen]

Comment: Acho que faltou alguns aí: 1) Fazer anotações em perfis que são visíveis apenas a outros moderadores. 2) Acessar o teacher lounge. 3) Ter acesso ao PII também (isso é o nome real do usuário e o e-mail?) 4) Colocar e tirar tags com nomes vermelhos de perguntas do meta. 5) Configurar a coloração de sintaxe em determinadas tags. 6) Acho que alguma coisa sobre correlacionar IPs acerca de suspeitas de sockpuppeting? 7) Em sites normais de língua inglesa, remover perguntas da HNQ ou marcá-las para nunca entrarem na HNQ. 8) Mesclar contas duplicadas de usuário. 9) Fazer um super-ping em chats.

Comment: 10) Ser moderador em um site te torna moderador em todos os chats da rede. 11) Alguma ferramenta para rastrear suspeitas de manipulação de votos em perguntas e respostas? 12) Acesso ao teams para moderadores da SE.

Comment: Ah, foi mal quanto ao 8. Só vi agora que eu já te perguntei isso há 5 anos atrás.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Infelizmente o item 8 depende dos CMs. Tem coisa aí que é melhor eu não comentar rs. Ah, e o teacher's lounge não é mais usado.