# Eleição Para Moderadores da Comunidade 2018

Tags: debate, eleição, moderadores

Começaram as Eleições para Moderadores 2018!

Teremos 3 períodos diferentes durante as eleições:

1. Candidatura
2. Primárias
3. Eleições

Eleições costumam durar entre duas e três semanas, mas isso varia de acordo com o número de candidatos.

Para mais detalhes, e saber como participar, visite

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election

Caso você tenha mais perguntas sobre o processo de eleição, ou para os candidatos, pergunte no meta!
Basta usar a tag [eleição](/questions/tagged/elei%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Comment: Boa sorte a quem for participar e espero que a comunidade escolha os que entendem de verdade a visão do site e não pessoas só por causa de algum suporte técnico que recebeu no passado. Aguardo ansiosamente pela adição de uma pessoa que ajudem com o bem estar de nossa comunidade tão querida e com isto espero que também faça alguns veteranos voltarem a participar mais.

Comment: Será escolhido apenas UM novo moderador? Ou teremos mais?

Comment: Uma vaga apenas.]

Comment: Leitura relevante: [Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3963/70) e [Central de ajuda - Quem são os moderadores do site e o que fazem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Answer (score 16):

Esta eleição está ocorrendo porque as tarefas administrativas do site estão pesadas demais para a equipe atual. Em especial eu estou um pouco sobrecarregado e preciso diminuir o ritmo. Um dos moderadores deixará o cargo para dar lugar a um novo, portanto poderemos votar em apenas uma pessoa.

O perfil de um bom moderador para este cenário é:

- estar disponível
- entender a comunidade, saber o que precisa ser feito para manter a ordem, tomar boas decisões, que são muitas e todos os dias
- não se importar em pagar um preço por ser moderador.

Me desculpe se desagrada alguém, mas quem não pode ou não quer contribuir bastante com todas as tarefas invisíveis que um moderador tem que cuidar, não será um membro ideal, não ajudará resolver o problema que temos hoje, que resultou nesta eleição. Moderadores não podem se omitir para "ficar bem na fita", não podem querer ser populares, porque sempre cai no populismo.

Ser moderador não é fácil, não é simples. Apanha de todo mundo, já que sempre tem alguém que gostaria que você atuasse de outra forma. Sempre há reclamações de que você faz pouco, muito, ou o indesejado. Quase toda decisão que desagrada alguém vem seguida de retaliação por alguns membros, ainda que algumas retaliações sejam brancas. É preciso entender isso.

É comum quem se candidata ter ilusão que é só benesse e que a grama do vizinho é mais verde. Espero que todos os candidatos tenham a noção da dificuldade. Inclusive por conta disto devo fazer uma [pergunta de eleição anterior](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5204/101) adaptada para esta. A pessoa precisa saber onde está se metendo e que vai conseguir dar conta de tudo o que promete.

A eleição está ocorrendo por uma necessidade mais minha e com sugestão de outro moderador (não sei se ele quer ser citado), por isso preciso ter certeza que ela atenderá o objetivo de agregar e de fazer o trabalho dos outros moderadores mais fácil e não mais difícil.

Nem espero, embora fosse bom, que a pessoa seja mais atuante que eu porque sou meio fora do padrão :) mas precisa ser acima da média atual, para fazê-la subir. E acredite, a média não é tão baixa assim. Tem tarefas nos bastidores do site que muitos nem imaginam.

Ser moderador "diamante" é diferente de ser usuário normal. Tudo o que você faz hoje no site pode continuar fazendo sem ser moderador, como moderador fará outras coisas, é totalmente diferente. Se você é um ótimo usuário e até um bom moderador comunitário, tenha os meus parabéns e agradecimento, acho que posso falar por toda comunidade, mas saiba que moderar "oficialmente" exige outro esforço. Você só percebe quando está dentro.

Algumas descrições atuais parecem candidatura para quaisquer outras coisas, mas não para moderador do site, daquelas que a pessoa promete te contar o que ele fará só depois que estiver eleita, porque nem ela sabe do que se trata o cargo. É um péssimo sinal quando um candidato promete coisas que um moderador não deveria fazer, ou sequer tem poderes para tal.

Se tem dúvidas, o meta e o chat está pra isso.

Então por favor, se você se candidatou ou candidatará, pense se realmente é o que quer e se dará conta do que precisa ser feito, e não apenas do que você gostaria de fazer.

---

Esta eleição foi complicado, tivemos candidato fazendo propaganda, falando mal de todo mundo na campanha, prometendo coisas que não tem controle, e nem vou falar de suspeitas que levantaram. Para as próximas quem for se candidatar entenda que aqui até é um microcosmo da sociedade, mas não precisamos reproduzir os mesmos defeitos de uma campanha eleitoral universal que tem esse jogo todo por envolve muito dinheiro, aqui não tem nada disto, podemos ser mais lisos e tranquilos.

Comment: Complemento: [Diferença de Moderador ♦ para Usuário Confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3963/70) e [Central de ajuda - Quem são os moderadores do site e o que fazem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Answer (score 10):

Em todas as eleições na rede Stack Exchange, você pode escolher até 3 candidatos. A ordem que os candidatos são escolhidos importa: O primeiro candidato escolhido tem preferência sobre o segundo e o segundo sobre o terceiro.

Isso faz bastante sentido no caso de eleições com várias vagas de moderadores em aberto. No entanto, deve-se notar que nesta eleição há apenas uma vaga em aberto. Então deve-se prestar atenção quanto a isso porque o que mais importará será apenas o primeiro voto.

O algoritmo de votação utilizado é o [Meek STV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/176034). As vantagens deste algoritmo é que dispensa a necessidade de segundo turno explícito (ou terceiro turno, etc), funciona para eleições onde existam 2 ou mais vagas a ser preenchidas e reduz a necessidade e a motivação de votar-se taticamente (voto útil). O funcionamento matemático preciso desse algoritmo é complicado de explicar, mas de forma simplificada ele efetua várias rodadas de votos.

Em cada rodada, o Meek STV ou ele elege um candidato que tenha alcançado o número de votos necessários e transfere os votos excedentes para demais candidatos (no caso de haver várias vagas em aberto) ou se nenhum tiver sido eleito na rodada e nem tiver votos excedentes a serem transferidos, elimina o candidato mais fraco e transfere os votos dele para os demais candidatos. A transferência dos votos obedece a ordem de votação de cada eleitor. Se você votou nos candidatos A, B e C nessa ordem, o Meek STV vai inicialmente considerar que você votou apenas no candidato A. Se em uma das rodadas do Meek STV, o candidato A for eliminado, então ele vai passar a considerar que o seu voto foi no candidato B. Se numa rodada posterior, o B também for eliminado, ele vai considerar que você votou no candidato C.

Isso significa que na prática, como só temos uma vaga de moderador disponível, o seu segundo voto só será considerado se o seu primeiro candidato tiver sido eliminado sem que algum outro tenha sido eleito e o voto no terceiro candidato só será considerado se os dois primeiros tiverem sido eliminados sem que nenhum tenha sido eleito. A vantagem disso é que elimina a necessidade de haver segundo turno. A desvantagem é que muita gente pode acabar se confundindo.

Inclusive, devido a forma como esse processo funciona, é possível que o detentor da maior votação bruta como primeiro candidato acabe não sendo o vencedor. Vou pegar um [exemplo do metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276396/176034). Imagine que os votos tenham sido assim:

```
Porcentagem | 1ª escolha | 2ª escolha | 3ª escolha
----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------
33%         | Trump      | N/A        | N/A
22%         | Rubio      | Cruz       | N/A
22%         | Cruz       | Rubio      | N/A
 8%         | Bush       | Rubio      | Cruz
 8%         | Kasich     | Rubio      | Cruz
 7%         | Carson     | Cruz       | Rubio
```

Esta eleição é polarizada. Os eleitores de Trump votam nele e não querem saber de ninguém mais. Os demais eleitores se dividem em outros candidatos, mas não votam em Trump. Neste caso, o Meek STV eliminaria o Carson na primeira rodada, transferindo os votos dele para Cruz e resultaria numa nova distribuição de votos assim:

```
Porcentagem | 1ª escolha | 2ª escolha | 3ª escolha
----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------
33%         | Trump      | N/A        | N/A
29%         | Cruz       | Rubio      | N/A
22%         | Rubio      | Cruz       | N/A
 8%         | Bush       | Rubio      | Cruz
 8%         | Kasich     | Rubio      | Cruz
```

Outras rodadas iriam sendo feitas, onde candidatos seriam eliminados até que no final teríamos isso:

```
Porcentagem | 1ª escolha
----------- | ----------
67%         | Rubio
33%         | Trump
```

Ou seja, embora Trump tenha tido a maior votação bruta como primeiro candidato, ele acaba perdendo para Rubio devido as escolhas de segundo e terceiro candidato.

Quando os votos de um eleitor são todos para candidatos já eliminados, o voto dele é considerado branco ou nulo e desconsiderado. Isso é especialmente bastante factível de acontecer quando o eleitor não escolhe todos os três candidatos, escolhendo apenas dois ou apenas um (os demais são então considerados brancos).

Há mais umas complicações no algoritmo, tal quando votos são transferidos para candidatos já eleitos e tem que ser novamente transferidos. Com isso, a proporção de votos excedentes a serem transferidos acaba introduzindo o conceito de voto fracionário, o que acaba forçando mais rodadas para ajustar as coisas e produzindo números de votações bastante quebrados. Por exemplo, se você votou nos candidatos X e Y (nesta ordem) e o candidato X precisava de 80 votos para se eleger mas recebeu 100, então ele vai considerar que 80% do seu voto foi para o candidato X e 20% para o candidato Y. No entanto, acredito que não há como casos assim acontecerem quando há somente uma vaga em aberto. Um exemplo de uma votação assim ocorreu na [primeira eleição para o Worldbuilding](https://www.opavote.com/results/4895722432364544/0), que com 10 candidatos para 4 vagas, precisou de 22 rodadas no Meek STV para decidir os eleitos (e o resultado acabou sendo os 4 candidatos com as maiores votações como primeiro candidato).

Então, peço a todos os eleitores se atentarem a isso para evitar confusão posterior.